# Don't understand Vertex Shader Translation

Tags: java, c++, opengl, glsl

I need to translate vertices by an X and a Y value. I have tried the code below with a uniform of the translation I want but it doesn't work.

`translationX` and `translationY` were assigned to uniforms with code similar to:

```
int my_value_loc = glGetUniformLocation(shader, "translationX");
glUniform1f(my_value_loc, 10.0f);
```

Here is my shader:

```
#version 330
uniform float translationX;
uniform float translationY;
void main(){
    gl_Position=vec4(vVertex.x+translationX, vVertex.y+translationY, 0.0,
}
```

Comment: where is vVertex coming from?  If this is a vertex shader you should be assigning it with something like "glVertexAttribPointer(positionAttribute, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), 0); 
    "

Comment: See this [introduction to the transformations that are used in the OpenGL pipeline](http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_transform.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd prefer sending a translation matrix.

shader code:

```
uniform mat4 trans;
attribute vec3 vertex;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = trans * vec4(vertex, 1.0);
}
```

Comment: I have never used shaders before, but all I need to do is add on this translated variable, I don't know if I should use a matrix or even how to use one.

Comment: Well, either use a translation vector, or a translation matrix. But please don't send individual components. It's awkward, error prone, inefficient and tedious. Also you'll not get around matrices in the long run.